# Capybara with nested tags

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, capybara

Given this HTML fragment

```
<ul>
  <li>Product 1<span><a href="#">Remove</a></span></li>
  <li>Product 2<span><a href="#">Remove</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

What's a clean way to get the list of products as an array?:

```
['Product 1', 'Product 2']
```

I want the text of the `li` elements but not of the `span` tags.

---

Update:

This works:

```
all('ul li').map{|e| e.native.children.first.text}
```

but can it be improved? I'm not keen on using 'native' as it may be not work with all Capybara drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
all(:xpath, '//ul/li/text()[1]').map(&:text)
```

Comment: Indeed it does - and it seems you don't even need the [1] part. Seems it's one of the situations where you need the power of Xpath rather than a CSS query.

Comment: If you have any extra whitespace or newlines around the link or span tags you might need the [1].

Comment: It takes the first text node in each `li` element if there are more than one.

Comment: The css equivalent wold be: `ul > li > text()[1]`

Comment: @pguardiario, that's a hybrid CSS + XPath. CSS doesn't have text node selection. Perhaps it works in Capybara because it gets translated to XPath under the hood.

Comment: @mark thomas - Good point but I think you can say that about all css selectors